# EfficientNet does not seem to present in keras.applications

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the EfficientNet model from tf.keras but for some reason this does not seem to work.

```
import tensorflow.keras.applications as apps
help(apps)
```

does not list `EfficientNetB0` as a model. 
Similarly,

```
import tensorflow.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0
```

prints

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0'

My current Keras.applications is 1.0.8 which seems to be the latest version. My Keras version is 2.2.5 and my tensorflow 1.15. Also, the same behavior is apparent for stand alone keras version.

Shouldn't this be resolved by the keras.application version only? Does it has to do with the tensorflow version (meaning maybe only tf 2 can use them?). And finally, is there a work around this issue that I can use?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of [`EfficientNetB0`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/EfficientNetB0), it says "Note: This API is new and only available in `tf-nightly`." In 2.2.0 I can access it if I do `from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB0`, but in 1.15 is just not there at all. Maybe you can just [download the Python module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/efficientnet.py) and it will work for you...

Comment: I think `pip install tf-nightly` should fix this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, the modules `EfficientNetB0` through `EfficientNetB7` are only available in the nightly build of tensorflow keras which is unstable. you can install this build by `pip install tf-nightly`

Answer (score 2):

The EfficientNet models are available in TensorFlow version 2.3.0 and later.